# Excel: COUNTIF but the cells have "<" in the name

Tags: excel, countif

I want to use COUNTIF on a range of cells, and some of them look like "<1000" to indicate "less than 1000"

I want to count how many cells have "<1000" as text, but when I use COUNTIF it interprets the cell, I think, as if I were asking "how many cells in this range are less than 1000 lexicographically."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this version assuming data in column A

`=COUNTIF(A:A,"=<1000")`

Comment: This worked flawlessly, thanks so much. I can accept this answer in 10m